# How to pull results from database and store in numeric array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am wondering how I can change the code below, so that I can pull the results form the database and store them as a numeric array. I have tried searching for an answer online and I know you use SQLI_NUM, but I haven't been able to implement it. Any help would be really appreciated.

/

```
$lecturers_temp = array();
$i = 0;
$q3 = "SELECT `uninum` FROM `availabilityindex` ORDER BY `availability`";
$result3 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q3);
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $lecturers_temp = $row3['uninum']; //

    $lecturers_temp[$i] = $row3['uninum']; //'uninum'
    //echo $lecturers_temp [$i] . "<BR><BR>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a numeric array, do you mean you want `$row3['uninum'];` to be numeric rather than a string?

Comment: You may need to gove us an example of what you mean

Comment: Sorry, I meant I want to be able to refer to the results by using numeric indexes like $lecturers_temp [0], $lecturers_temp [1] etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple you dont actually have to do anything clever at all you just load each row into `arrayname[]` PHP will look after incrementing the array index automatically.

```
$lecturers_temp = array();

$q3 = "SELECT `uninum` FROM `availabilityindex` ORDER BY `availability`";

$result3 = mysqli_query($dbcon,$q3);
if ( ! $result3 ) {
    echo mysqli_error($dbcon);
}

while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result3, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $lecturers_temp[] = $row3['uninum']; //
}
```

You should never use the `@` error supression on a mysqli statement. Its always best to know that something has gone wrong. Of course on a live system you would want to log these errors to a file so that admin s can check for errors and users do not see uninteligable errors.

Comment: Many thanks RiggsFolly! Much appreciated and I will mark it as answered in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lecturers_temp = array();
$i = 0;
$q3 = "SELECT `uninum` FROM `availabilityindex` ORDER BY `availability`";
$result3 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q3);
$row = $result3->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
...
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.